# DropDownListFor не выбирает значение

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Как сделать так, чтобы в `DropDownListFor` отображалось то значение, которое находится в `SelectedStatusId`? Сейчас отображается первое по счету в независимости от значения `SelectedStatusId`

**В контроллере**

```
List<SelectListItem> Statuses = new List<SelectListItem>();
Statuses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Passed", Value = "PSS" });
Statuses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Failed", Value = "FL" });
Statuses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Blocked", Value = "BLCK" });
Statuses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Not run", Value = "NR" });

ViewBag.Statuses = new SelectList(Statuses, "Value", "Text");
```

**Во вьюшке**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.SelectedStatusId,
(SelectList)ViewBag.Statuses,
new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас гремучая смесь из нескольких ошибок, которые накладываются друг на друга -- и поэтому вы никак не можете разобраться.

Допустим, у нас есть свой какой-то кастомный статус:

```
public class MyStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

И он обычно может храниться в базе, но мы создадим его вручную и передадим в представление:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var statuses = new[]
    {
        new MyStatus {Id = 1, Title = "New"},
        new MyStatus {Id = 2, Title = "Open"},
        new MyStatus {Id = 3, Title = "Stopped"},
    };

    var model = new SomeModel {SelectedStatusId = 2, Statuses = statuses};

    return this.View(model);
}
```

(Я очень не люблю передачу через `ViewBag` и всем рекомендую использовать строго типизованные модели)

Ваша веб-форма будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
@model MyApp.WebUI.Models.SomeModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Home"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedStatusId,
            Model.Statuses.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Title,
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = x.Id == Model.SelectedStatusId
            }),
            new { @class = "form-control" }
        )
    </div>
}
```

Пример подобран специально именно под вас.

Во-первых, у меня `SelectedStatusId` -- это честный int и в модели тоже int.
У вас `SelectedStatusId` непонятно что, а в `SelectListItem` -- строки.

Во-вторых, посмотрите на определение класса `SelectListItem` -- я заполнил вручную `Selected` сравнивая значение `Model.SelectedStatusId` и Id текущего элемента.

Это работает. Это будет первый пример, который я вам хочу показать.

Далее. Вместо того, чтобы вручную работать с `SelectListItem`, создавая его через лямбды -- вы можете использовать готовый хелпер `SelectList`.
В контроллере ничего не меняю, а представление станет таким:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Home"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedStatusId,
            new SelectList(Model.Statuses,
                           nameof(MyStatus.Id),
                           nameof(MyStatus.Title),
                           Model.SelectedStatusId),
            new { @class = "form-control" }
            )
    </div>
}
```

Это тоже работает. Мы в `SelectList` передаём данные, говорим, какие поля читать и говорим, какой элемент выбран.

Обратите внимание. Ваши статусы уже имеют поля `Text` и `Value`, совпадающие с тем, что ожидает `SelectListItem`, я специально подбирал пример, чтобы уйти от этого (это только запутывает).

PS Вы использовали служебный класс фреймворка вместо класса предметной области. `SelectListItem` - это класс из слоя представления, пусть view сам решает, как отображать.