# Валидация ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, json, mvc, валидация

У меня есть два класса

```
public class Owner
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Почта")]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HomeRepair> HomeRepairs { get; set; }
    public Owner()
    {
        HomeRepairs = new List<HomeRepair>();
    }
    ...
}
public class HomeRepair
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Адрес")]
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Метод контроллера

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SelectList owners = new SelectList(db.Owners, "Name", "Name");
        ViewBag.Owners = owners;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HomeRepair homeRepair, Owner owner)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            homeRepair.RepairStatus = "Ремонт запланирован";
            db.HomeRepairs.Add(homeRepair);
            foreach (var i in db.Owners)
            {
                if (i.Name == owner.Name)
                {
                    i.HomeRepairs.Add(homeRepair);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Представление

```html
@model TestTask.Models.HomeRepair
@using TestTask.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Добавление дома";
}

<h2>Добавление дома</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h4>Дом</h4>
    <div class="editor-label"><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)</b></div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label"><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RepairStatus)</b></div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Ремонт запланирован
    </div>
    <h4>Владелец</h4>
    Owner owner = new Owner();

    <div id="selectOwner" class="editor-label"><b>Выберите владельца</b></div>
    <div id="selectOwnerDropDownList" class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Name", ViewBag.Owners as SelectList)
    </div>

    <p>
        <a id="addNewOwner" class="addLink">Добавить нового владельца</a>
    </p>
    <div id="addOwner">

    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
    </p>

}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $('.addLink').one('click', function ()
        {
            $("#selectOwner").hide();
            $("#selectOwnerDropDownList").hide();
            $("#addNewOwner").hide();
            var htmlAdd = "<div class='editor-label'><b>Имя</b></div>" +
                          "<div class='editor-field'>" +
                          "<input type='text' name ='owner.Name' value=''>" +
                          "<span class='field-validation-valid text-danger'" +
                          "data-valmsg-for='owner.Name' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>" +
                          "</div>" +
                          "<div class='editor-label'><b>Email</b></div>" +
                          "<div class='editor-field'>" +
                          "<input type='text' name='owner.Email' value=''>" +
                          "<span class='field-validation-valid text-danger'" +
                          "data-valmsg-for='owner.Email' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>" +
                          "</div>";
                          $('#addOwner').append(htmlAdd)
        })
    </script>
    
    
}
```

Вот сама форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на "Добавить нового владельца":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после нажатия на "Добавить" выскакивает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Валидация полей HomeRepair отлично работает, а Owner - нет. В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Потому что поле Owner - необязательное, поэтому если оно не задано - это не считается ошибкой. Давайте вы перефразируете вопрос. Вернёмся к тому, что именно вы хотите за данные ввести (у вас же нет никакого текстового пояснения к коду) и тогда мы будем говорить о том, что ваш код не под эту задачу заточен, а под какую-то другую. Посмотрите [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918011/213987), может быть предварительно станет что-то понятнее.

Comment: У вас тут одна явная ошибка, но если начать разбираться в том, как должно работать -- то можно очень долго отвечать на вопрос и непонятно, где проводить границу "на вопрос дан исчерпывающий ответ". Конкретно эта ошибка на скриншоте появляется от того, что нельзя так просто взять и скастовать к SelectList: нужны поля Text и Value, посмотреть правильное направление можно в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/665719/213987). Вообще же если нет на экшене `[Post]` над этим экшеном (их два делают), то могут быть и ещё ошибки.